# Searching for editors for an .droid and .yydebug editors

Tags: android, file, editor, filenames, viewer

I'm trying to open some android game files, I am using WinRar to open the obb files and now i'm stuck, I'm need to open .droid file and .yydebug file..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are compiled files and cannot be opened in a easy way...